The derivative of a function of several variables
Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by: $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x\sin y - y\sin x}{x^2+y^2}\ &\text{if}\ (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0\ &\text{if}\ (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}.$$
I want to check the continuousness of it's partial derivatives at the point $(0,0)$. I know that:
$$\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\left(y^2-x^2\right)\sin y-y\left(x^2+y^2\right)\cos x+2xy\sin x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\ &\text{if}\ (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0\ &\text{if}\ (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$ and $$\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\left(y^2-x^2\right)\sin x+x\left(x^2+y^2\right)\cos y-2xy\sin y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\ &\text{if}\ (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0\ &\text{if}\ (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}.$$
The answer in my exercise book tells these ones are not continuous at $(0,0)$. I tried to let $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along these segments: $x=0$, $y=0$, $x=y$ but it's no use. Please give me a hint.

Hint: Switch to polar coordinates.

@OmarDennaoui the partial derivatives will be
$$\dfrac{\cos 2\phi\sin(r\sin\phi)-r\sin\phi\cos(r\cos\phi)+2\sin2\phi\sin(r\cos\phi)}{r^2}$$ right ?
But when I try $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, the limits when $r\to0$ are equal to $0$. Can you give 2 different values of $\phi$ ?

The double limit $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ covers all approaches to $(0,0)$ not just two or three of them. Look for a $\phi$ that gives a different answer as $r \to \infty$. The factors with $r$ inside a trig function will go to $\sin 0$ or $\cos 0$ as $r \to 0$, regardless of the value of $\phi$.
